# Java regex matching everything except a fixed terminal

Tags: java, regex

Given a terminating token `<term> ::= "()\n}"`, 
Is it possible to match

`"{" <anything-except-term> <term>`

using Java regex?

EDIT: More specifically, I have a source file (Scala, as it happens) of the form

```
{
...
()
}
```

Where `...` is "all the rest of the Scala code.

What I actually want is to extract the `...` bit, but I'd settle for just matching the whole thing.

Comment: Please add a little bit more context. You are designing a grammar? Which tool/library are you using? Btw. in regular expressions there is no such thing as a NOT operator.

Comment: More context now added.

Answer (score 2):

A regex to match `"{" <anything-except-term> <term>`, where `<term>` is `"()\n}"` is easy enough:

```
\{          Match "{"
.*?         Match anything, but stop as soon as the following matches
\(\)\n\}    Match <term>, i.e. "()\n}"
```

Now, you probably want to capture the content too, so add a `()` capture group.

The `.` doesn't actually match "anything" unless you enable [`DOTALL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) mode, which can be done inline by adding `(?s)`.

And technically you don't need to escape the `}`.

So, the result is: `(?s)\{(.*?)\(\)\n}`
As a Java literal, that is: `"(?s)\\{(.*?)\\(\\)\n}"`

See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zA2wP2/1) for demo.

Answer (score 0):

Using a tempered dot, although being expensive is a neat solution:

```
\{((?:(?!\(\)\s+\})[\s\S])*)
```

Explanation:

```
\{                      # Match a literal {
(                       # Start capturing group (1)
    (?:                     # Start no capturing group (a)
        (?!\(\)\s+\})           # If immediate next positions are not going to be a ()\n}
        [\s\S]                  # If yes match next character
    )*                      # Repeat it zero or more times - End of non-capturing group (a)
)                       # End of capturing group (1)
```

As a Java string:

```
\\{((?:(?!\\(\\)\\s+\\})[\\s\\S])*)
```

I simply used `\s` instead of `\r?\n`. You may want to change it.

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/oV3jU6/3)

Answer (score 0):

This will extract just the input you want (in one line):

```
String guts = input.replaceAll("(?s).*?(?<=\\{\\R).*(?=\\R\\(\\)\\R}).*", "$1");
```

I've used `\R` (introduced in Java 8), to match "newline" on any platform.

---

This expects there to be matching input, if not the original string with be returned as-is. If you want to get fancy and return a blank when there's no match, make the important bit optional so there's *always* a match:

```
String guts = input.replaceAll("(?s).*?(?:(?<=\\{\\R).*(?=\\R\\(\\)\\R}))?.*", "$1");
```

Comment: It's greedy. It won't capture appropriate part if there are multiple similar strings or if there is one another `<term>` somewhere else in input. It's greedy. It has three greedy dots (first two are effective). It means lots of backtracks in case of dealing with a large input string.

Comment: @revo Ummm yes -that's exactly what OP wants. His input has only one target per *I have a source file (Scala, as it happens) of the form...*. There are no "multiple similar strings" with which to deal. (btw re backtracking, yes I accidentally left out the initial reluctant `?` in the first version - with that in, it should perform well).

Comment: By that mean, yet it is not bulletproof and lots of backtracks are likely to happen.